# If $f$ and $g \circ f$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are defined and finite valued on $\mathbb{R}$ if $f$ and $g \circ f$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ then $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

let $f(x)=1$ and   $g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ is $\mathbb{Q}$} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ }
\end{cases}$

- Clearly $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g $ is not conitinous on $\mathbb{R}$
- $g \circ f(x)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
- therefore $f$ and $g \circ f$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ but $g$ is not

Can anyone verify my answer? Is it correct or wrong?

Comment: What does "finite valued" mean

Comment: The statement is wrong, and you have provided a valid counterexample.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you I have doubt that it is valid counterexample or not

Comment: It's correct. In fact composing by a constant function is constant so it continuous whatever the other function is continuous or not.

Comment: @Essaidi thank you